# Understanding "discrete" sensors in ipmi

Tags: ipmi

Can anyone describe how a discrete sensor works in the IPMI world?

In the IPMI specification there are "sensors" for processor and memory that are of discrete type.

Is there really a SW/Firmware entity monitoring memory per say for ECC errors and then generates some event if something occurs? If so, is IPMI doing the actual testing to find ECC errors? Trying to grasp what is occurring under the covers of such a sensor.

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two types of sensors in IPMI: Threshold and discrete. A threshold sensor is essentially an analog sensor to measure things like temperatures, voltages or fan speeds. A discrete sensor is just a binary sensor that only has two states, e.g. on/off, present/absent or NoError/Error. These sensors are  grouped into a single 16bit value that must be interpreted as a bit field. And yes, this naming sucks because it suggests a very different meaning of the term "discrete".

How that sensor actually works is of course dependent on the measured item and the specific implementation, but in case of ECC RAM, IPMI will not (and could not!) check for errors itself. Instead, one approach to detect this error would be to watch the signal lines between the RAM modules and the memory controller that report an ECC error. If it detects a signal on those lines, the management interface could generate an IPMI error event  that is independent of the error handling the primary hardware and OS will perform. Another approach would be to have the memory controller actively report that error to the management interface.

Comment: Great feedback. My understanding is very similar to what you stated. If we keep with the ECC example, what part of that is the "sensor", just the logical notion that we are sensing an error? Obviously there is some small piece of code that would need to manage this stuff. So when an application polls said "sensor" it's really asking another piece of software if they have noticed any ECC errors per say from the memory controller.

Comment: @user_ABCD Yes. it is logical. for more info refer to spec https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/ipmi-second-gen-interface-spec-v2-rev1-1.pdf